# In Elasticsearch, how to know which element in the array is chosen by the fuzzysearch when querying against a list

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, fuzzy-search

I have a tricky case and want to consult the experts here.
We store our user info in Elasticsearch, an user may have different name aliases, all stored in a "names" array like below

```
"names" : [
            {
              "userName" : "John Jerry",
              "nameType" : "Primary Name"
            },
            {
              "userName" : "John The Great",
              "nameType" :"Also Known As"
            },
            {
              "userName" : "Jerry Our Father",
              "nameType" :"Also Known As"
            }
]
```

When we search for a user name, let say "**jone great**" we build a fuzzysearch like below

```
{
    "span_near": {
      "clauses": [
        {
          "span_multi": {
            "match": {
              "fuzzy": {
                "names.userName": {
                  "value": "jone",
                  "fuzziness": "1",
                  "prefix_length": 0,
                  "max_expansions": 50,
                  "transpositions": true,
                  "boost": 1
                }
              }
            },
            "boost": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "span_multi": {
            "match": {
              "fuzzy": {
                "names.userName": {
                  "value": "great",
                  "fuzziness": "1",
                  "prefix_length": 0,
                  "max_expansions": 50,
                  "transpositions": true,
                  "boost": 1
                }
              }
            },
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "slop": 2,
      "in_order": false,
      "boost": 1
    }
},
```

This query will return the user above, whose alias is "John The Great" because this name has a good score against the input "jone great"

The question is how do I know **programmatically** which name in the array is chosen by the fuzzysearch. Imagine a user has 100 name aliases, is there a way to tell Elasticsearch to point out which alias is the reason that user is chosen as a match?

In our current approach, we write a piece of code to scan through all the name aliases of the user returned by ES and pick the best possible name aliases. This is time consuming, especially in case an user has nearly 100 name aliases.

It would be the best if there is something we can add in the ES query and make it highlight the name it chooses in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
Just do a nested query with the same clauses that you have and specify "inner_hits" : {"size" : 1}.
That will return the top matching nested array element.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that and update the result here :) (Sorry for the late response)